# C# version of remove_reference<T>?

Tags: c#

Is there an equivalent of C++'s `std::remove_reference<T>` in C#?

I have a `String` and `String&`, and in my project right now these should be considered equivalent.

In C++ I'd do something like `is_same<T1, remove_reference<T2>::type>::value`, but in C# I cannot figure out any good way to compare these types.  The best I've come up with (and it's horrible) is:

```cs
if (
       0 == String.Compare(type1.Name, type2.Name + "&")
    || 0 == String.Compare(type1.Name + "&", type2.Name)
)
```

I've tried `Type.IsAssignableFrom`, and looking through all the various properties, but nothing has seemed to work so far.

Comment: And here we see 2 living legends answering your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is:

```
if (type2.IsByRef && type2.GetElementType() == type1)
```

See the [`GetElementType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getelementtype?view=netframework-4.8) and [`IsByRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isbyref?view=netframework-4.8) documentation for details.

Note that the `IsByRef` part is required to avoid this being true for `string[]` as well as `string&` for example.

Comment: Beat me by 21 seconds!

Comment: Worked!  Thanks!  (in 6 minutes I can accept it as an answer.)  I was looking at `GetElementType` but didn't know how to get it to work.  I'm still new to C# :)

Comment: There should be a "Jon is already looking at it" UI element. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can call `GetElementType` on the `Type` object for `string&`, and it will return the type object for `string`.